# How elasticsearch decides must and filter terms in same query?

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query includes must and filter contexts in same query.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title":   "Search"        }},
        { "match": { "content": "Elasticsearch" }}
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "status": "published" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

if there are some documents that matches with must logic but not matches with filer logic, so I am getting no result? Is filter most important?
How works this query order? First must logic and then filter logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it will match all the conditions of MUST & FILTERS. You can see MUST & FILTER something like AND query. So the query will go like `title="search" AND content="Elasticsearch" AND status="published"`.

The only difference is MUST contributes to scoring where FILTER is not.

So if you hit same query like below,

```json
GET /_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title":   "Search"        }},
        { "match": { "content": "Elasticsearch" }},
        { "term":  { "status": "published" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You will see the different `_score` value with same result.

So simple is if you want to ignore scoring just use filter.

Mostly filters are use with conditions like `<`,`>`,`<=`,`>=`,`=` or where you don't want score.

**Note** : Frequently used filters will be cached automatically by Elasticsearch, to speed up performance.

Check more in [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: Thanks Ashish can I use <,>,<=,>=,= in must query?

Comment: If it is same `and` logic why filter added to elasticsearch?

Comment: The only difference is MUST contributes to scoring where FILTER is not. YES you can use <,>,<=,>=,= in must query